# Where is the pod file in xcode located?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to locate the pod file in my xcode project so that I can install the SwiftyJSON module via cocoa pods. I don't seem to find the pod file in my project structure. Is this something that one needs to create?

Comment: It is duplicate question. First follow this answer and related answers, if still you facing issue then post a new ques.

Comment: Did you install cocoa pod using command sudo gem install cocoapods?